# Weird behavior with multipages jquery mobile

Tags: php, json, jquery-mobile

finally I made some change in the code and all went ok but I found a strange behaviour.

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bugs Administration</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
<script>
 var content;

    $(document).bind('pageinit',function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/getbugs.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {



for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    content = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed-icon='arrow-r' data-expanded-icon='arrow-d' data-iconpos='right'><h3> " + 
    data[i].errorcode + ' - ' + data[i].title+ "</h3>" + "<ul data-role='listview' id='noth'>"



                    content = content +
                                           '<li>Project: ' + data[i].project+ '</li>' +
                                           '<li>type: ' + data[i].type + '</li>' +
                                           '<li>Status: ' + data[i].status + '</li>' +
                                           '<li>Severity: ' + data[i].severity + '</li>' +
                                           '<li>Browser: ' + data[i].browser + '</li>' +
                                           '<li>Creation date: ' + data[i].creationdate + '</li>'
                        content = content + '</ul>';     content = content + "</div>";$("#set").append( content );
                }


        $("#set").enhanceWithin();

            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="bugs">
    <header data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="Main" data-role="content">
        <h3>Lista de Errores</h3>
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="set"><div>        
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p>(c) Copyright 2014</p>
    </footer>
</div><!-- /page -->  
<div data-role="page" id="news">
    <header data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="Main" data-role="content">

     </div><!-- /content -->
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p>(c) Copyright 2014</p>
    </footer>
</div><!-- /page -->   
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this in Chrome, the bugs appears normally but a minute after  the application repeats the action added them twice

[image]

I tried different combinations but I don't know what's happenning with this

Comment: if you only want the ajax call once on the bugs page, try $(document).on('pagecreate', '#bugs', function (event){...});

Comment: I tried but nothing change, really there is something weird